# Huge data usage started last month - 4GB over mothly average

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, data-monitoring, htc-one-m8

I have an HTC One (M8) with Cyanogenmod 12 (12-20150625-snapshot-yng4nao09n-m8) which I have been using since June. Before that I had a different version of CM on the same phone and did a full reset. Late September, high data usage by the Android OS system showed up like the bogeyman out of nowhere. I've had a 3GB plan for 2 years and have never once gone over until now where I am over by 4GB.

Verified Backup and Sync is turned off for the phone and for photos. I also cleared the cache and data for Google Backup Transport, Google Play Services, Google Play Store, and Google Services Framework, rebooted, and thought I had the problem solved, but installed My Data Manager and waited.

The built in Data manager shows everything as Android OS, with no option for me to restrict. Data Manager caught it happening today and says its EasyAccessServices. What is EasyAccessServices, anyway? In All Apps the option to disable EasyAccessServices is greyed out.

Every data jump has been in the same amount: 0.64GB (650-680MB). It will happen at different times of the day, on random days. This has got me tearing my hair out in frustration. I've got some rollover data built up but I can't afford too much more of this.

**EDIT**: Its been explained that EasyAccessServices is the pointer/gesture app built in to the OS that basically acts as the touchscreen driver. I can't tell if the data was uploaded or downloaded, but maybe the app is trying to update itself and failing. Looks like `com.htc.easyaccessservice` is version 2.0.831094.

**EDIT2**: I can Force Stop the application. When I do I still can use all the gestures I can think of in NovaLauncher and Facebook.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: app data usage]
[image: IMG: my data monitoring app]
[image: IMG: easy access service]

Comment: Disable the service and reinstall it. See if that fixes things.

Comment: As stated Disable is greyed out

Comment: Should have noticed that, but yeah, that's incredibly odd. If you are locked from disabling it, you might be stuck against the wall with the only option being flashing the ROM again and hoping that the issue doesn't come back.

Comment: Easy access service apparently controls all of the phone gestures, so it's a good thing you cant turn it off. You wouldn't be able to do anything that requires any kind of slide, pinch, etc. Your only option seems to be to reset it. I have no idea why it would need data though.

Comment: Thank you. Reflash is probably in my future. I'm even more confused now as to why the simple gestures app is whacking my phone so hard. Who knows, probably the NSA uploading my text messages...lol. 

I'm going to catch it in the act and see if it is an upload or a download...

Comment: I'm guessing it is pulling some kind of update, but why it would do it over cellular, repetitively, and require that much data is beyond me.

Comment: The phone hasn't done anything bad since Oct 9. At that time I went to Settings -> Storage I reset all cached data which gave me back a full GB of space, and installed an application that can differentiate between phone data going up and down.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything I could think of, I did a factory reset on the phone. So far no more issues.